# Sequelize use ROW_NUMBER() instead of OFFSET and FETCH

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm noticing a different behaviour with using (`offset, fetch`) and `rownumber`.

When I use row number it returns the result I expect.

So my sequelize query looks like this:

```
 ClanModel.findAll({
    order: [["Wins", "DESC"]],
    offset: page * 5,
    limit: 5
 })
```

SQL query starting from the the first row

```
SELECT 
    [clid] AS [ClanId], [Name], [Wins], [Losses], 
    [totalPoint] AS [TotalPoints] 
FROM 
    [Clan] AS [Clan] 
ORDER BY 
    [Clan].[Wins] DESC 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Results in:

```
[ { Name: 'Test6'},
  { Name: 'Test5'},
  { Name: 'Test4'},
  { Name: 'Test3'},
  { Name: 'Test2'} ]
```

SQL query after the 5th result:

```
SELECT 
    [clid] AS [ClanId], [Name], [Wins], [Losses],
    [totalPoint] AS [TotalPoints] 
FROM 
    [Clan] AS [Clan] 
ORDER BY 
    [Clan].[Wins] DESC 
    OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Results in:

```
[ { Name: 'Test5'},
  { Name: 'Test4'},
  { Name: 'Test3'},
  { Name: 'Test2'},
  { Name: 'Test1'} ]
```

Row number query:

```
 SELECT 
     [Name], [Wins], [Losses], [TotalPoints] AS [TotalPoints]
 FROM 
     (SELECT
          [clid] AS [ClanId], [Name], [Wins], [Losses],
          [totalPoint] AS [TotalPoints], 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Wins]) AS RowNum
      FROM 
          [Clan]) as Clan
 WHERE 
     Clan.RowNum BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Returns the results I expect:

```
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9
Test10
```

My database records:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9
Test10
```

I'd like to use my sequelize model to get my data instead of using a plain sql query. But i can't find a way to use row number in sequelize.

Is there a way to still use sequelize to get my data?

Comment: You should edit your question and show the complete data, not just the `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the complete data.  So, this is a bit of speculation:  you have ties in the `wins` column.  The sorting for `order by` is not stable and not even consistent, meaning that ties can come back in any order.  So, fix this by including the name:

```
SELECT [clid] AS [ClanId], [Name], [Wins], [Losses], [totalPoint] AS [TotalPoints]
FROM [Clan] AS [Clan]
ORDER BY [Clan].[Wins] DESC, Clan.Name
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Assuming `Name` is unique, this will make the sort consistent.  If this works in SQL, then it should be easy to implement in sequelize.

Comment: This worked for me, all my wins were set to zero which was causing the problem.